# how to access a address element from below nested json object IN PHP

Tags: php, json

I want access to `addressLine`, `adminDistrict` from address element which is stored in json format IN PHP

```
{
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [
    {
      "estimatedTotal": 1,
      "resources": [
        {
          "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
          "bbox": [
            40.75594078242932,
            -74.0022632570927,
            40.76366621757067,
            -73.98866508290732
          ],
          "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
          "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              40.7598035,
              -73.99546417
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St",
            "adminDistrict": "NY",
            "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.",
            "countryRegion": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
            "intersection": {
              "baseStreet": "W 42nd St",
              "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave",
              "intersectionType": "Near",
              "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave"
            },
            "locality": "New York",
            "postalCode": "10036"
          },
          "confidence": "High",
          "entityType": "Address",
          "geocodePoints": [
            {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                40.7598035,
                -73.99546417
              ],
              "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
              "usageTypes": [
                "Display"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "matchCodes": [
            "Good"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0"
}

{
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [
    {
      "estimatedTotal": 1,
      "resources": [
        {
          "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
          "bbox": [
            40.75594078242932,
            -74.0022632570927,
            40.76366621757067,
            -73.98866508290732
          ],
          "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
          "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              40.7598035,
              -73.99546417
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St",
            "adminDistrict": "NY",
            "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.",
            "countryRegion": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
            "intersection": {
              "baseStreet": "W 42nd St",
              "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave",
              "intersectionType": "Near",
              "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave"
            },
            "locality": "New York",
            "postalCode": "10036"
          },
          "confidence": "High",
          "entityType": "Address",
          "geocodePoints": [
            {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                40.7598035,
                -73.99546417
              ],
              "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
              "usageTypes": [
                "Display"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "matchCodes": [
            "Good"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0"
}
```

Comment: assign that JSON to a variable in PHP. And use json_decode() on that variable

Comment: why to use json_decode(),when it is already coming in json format

Comment: to convert it in array

Comment: $JsonData = json_decode($result,true), and how to access the addressline from the array

Comment: check the answer...

Answer (score 0):

you need to access it by assigning it to the variable e.g. say

```
let a = { "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials", "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png", "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.", "resourceSets": [ { "estimatedTotal": 1, "resources": [ { "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1", "bbox": [ 40.75594078242932, -74.0022632570927, 40.76366621757067, -73.98866508290732 ], "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036", "point": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.7598035, -73.99546417 ] }, "address": { "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St", "adminDistrict": "NY", "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.", "countryRegion": "United States", "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036", "intersection": { "baseStreet": "W 42nd St", "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave", "intersectionType": "Near", "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave" }, "locality": "New York", "postalCode": "10036" }, "confidence": "High", "entityType": "Address", "geocodePoints": [ { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 40.7598035, -73.99546417 ], "calculationMethod": "Rooftop", "usageTypes": [ "Display" ] } ], "matchCodes": [ "Good" ] } ] } ], "statusCode": 200, "statusDescription": "OK", "traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0" }
```

then access it like this

```
console.log(a.resourceSets[0].resources[0].address)
```

Comment: They asked for it *IN PHP*

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*
if Array of JSON Object is returned then
Use following
*/
$json = '[{
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [
    {
      "estimatedTotal": 1,
      "resources": [
        {
          "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
          "bbox": [
            40.75594078242932,
            -74.0022632570927,
            40.76366621757067,
            -73.98866508290732
          ],
          "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
          "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              40.7598035,
              -73.99546417
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St",
            "adminDistrict": "NY",
            "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.",
            "countryRegion": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
            "intersection": {
              "baseStreet": "W 42nd St",
              "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave",
              "intersectionType": "Near",
              "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave"
            },
            "locality": "New York",
            "postalCode": "10036"
          },
          "confidence": "High",
          "entityType": "Address",
          "geocodePoints": [
            {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                40.7598035,
                -73.99546417
              ],
              "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
              "usageTypes": [
                "Display"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "matchCodes": [
            "Good"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0"
},
{
  "authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
  "brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
  "copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
  "resourceSets": [
    {
      "estimatedTotal": 1,
      "resources": [
        {
          "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
          "bbox": [
            40.75594078242932,
            -74.0022632570927,
            40.76366621757067,
            -73.98866508290732
          ],
          "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
          "point": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              40.7598035,
              -73.99546417
            ]
          },
          "address": {
            "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St",
            "adminDistrict": "NY",
            "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.",
            "countryRegion": "United States",
            "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
            "intersection": {
              "baseStreet": "W 42nd St",
              "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave",
              "intersectionType": "Near",
              "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave"
            },
            "locality": "New York",
            "postalCode": "10036"
          },
          "confidence": "High",
          "entityType": "Address",
          "geocodePoints": [
            {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [
                40.7598035,
                -73.99546417
              ],
              "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
              "usageTypes": [
                "Display"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "matchCodes": [
            "Good"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "statusCode": 200,
  "statusDescription": "OK",
  "traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0"
}]';

$array = json_decode($json);
foreach($array as $sub_array) {
    echo $sub_array->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->addressLine . "<br/>";
    echo $sub_array->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->adminDistrict . "<br/>";
}

/*
And if single JSON Object is returned then
Use following
*/
$json = '{
"authenticationResultCode": "ValidCredentials",
"brandLogoUri": "http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png",
"copyright": "Copyright © 2019 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.",
"resourceSets": [
{
  "estimatedTotal": 1,
  "resources": [
    {
      "__type": "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1",
      "bbox": [
        40.75594078242932,
        -74.0022632570927,
        40.76366621757067,
        -73.98866508290732
      ],
      "name": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
      "point": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          40.7598035,
          -73.99546417
        ]
      },
      "address": {
        "addressLine": "471 W 42nd St",
        "adminDistrict": "NY",
        "adminDistrict2": "New York Co.",
        "countryRegion": "United States",
        "formattedAddress": "471 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036",
        "intersection": {
          "baseStreet": "W 42nd St",
          "secondaryStreet1": "10th Ave",
          "intersectionType": "Near",
          "displayName": "W 42nd St and 10th Ave"
        },
        "locality": "New York",
        "postalCode": "10036"
      },
      "confidence": "High",
      "entityType": "Address",
      "geocodePoints": [
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            40.7598035,
            -73.99546417
          ],
          "calculationMethod": "Rooftop",
          "usageTypes": [
            "Display"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "matchCodes": [
        "Good"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
],
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "OK",
"traceId": "d551494203554f058cd3e2e72582f7b1|HK20271557|7.7.0.0|HK01EAP000001D0"
}';
$JsonData = json_decode($json); 
echo $JsonData->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->addressLine . "<br/>";
echo $JsonData->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->adminDistrict . "<br/>";
```

Comment: $JsonData = json_decode($result,true); 
foreach ($JsonData as $sub_array) {
echo $sub_array->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->addressLine . "<br/>";
  echo $sub_array->resourceSets[0]->resources[0]->address->adminDistrict . "<br/>";
 }blank page is coming

Comment: Please check that I have made the json response as array.Notice The Square brackets and comma in between json objects.

Comment: but that is coming from an api, how can i change it,into the above format

Comment: Is the API is returning in that exact format. And please remove the second parmeter from json_decode($result,true) and change it to json_decode($result).

Comment: Is the API is returning one json Object OR the whole that you have given in Question

Comment: whole just like in the question

Comment: If it is as you posted in question, then it is INVALID JSON. Multiple JSON Objects must be in array. OR That is response of multiple API calls.